# Can you redirect stdout, stderr to a fileappender in log4j2 v2.3?

Tags: java, logging, stdout, log4j2, jboss6.x

This is my log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="Log4JFile" fileName="/log/Log4JFile.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="Log4JFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I'm using Jboss and if you do not include a configuration file, `log4j` logs everything to `server.log`. I need to log all of the levels of `log4j` plus `stdout` and `stderr` to a separate file that is not the default one. How can I accomplish this without overriding the print method in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect from the Log4j ConsoleAppender to a Log4j FileAppender.

What you *can* do is in the scripts/commands that start your application, redirect the output of that command to a file.  The syntax for this is OS dependent but usually looks something like `command > file`. Multiple `>` characters can append to an existing file rather than overwrite it. (Also OS dependent.)

Comment: My colleague said we used to do this but it stops logging the output to the console. Do you know how to fix that issue?

Comment: If you want to capture the console output and persist it in a file, and at the same time monitor this output in real time, you can tail the log file.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Is it any complex and if not could you give me a quick example?